# don't show notification on notification bar from my application when it is running

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I work on application , this application shows notification every period on notification bar , so I want  when the broadcast receiver is called to show this notification check if the application now is used (I mean the application is running and the user now open it )don't show the notification on notification bar , please help me .

```
This is the set of alarm in oncreate:
Intent iAlarm=new Intent(HomePage.this, AlarmReciever.class);
     AlarmMan alarm=new AlarmMan();
     alarm.SetAlarm(HomePage.this,System.currentTimeMillis() , 60000, true, 7896) ;                                                                      
and this is onstop and on resume:                                          
@Override
protected void onStop() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStop();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
 filter.addDataScheme("package");
 filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
 AlarmReciever reciever1=new AlarmReciever();
    this.registerReceiver(reciever1,filter);
```

}

```
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onResume();




try{
 AlarmReciever reciever2=new AlarmReciever();
this.unregisterReceiver(reciever2);
}catch(Error e)
{

    Log.v("error in resume", e.getMessage());

}
```

}

```
This the setalarm function:
 public static  void SetAlarm (Context c , long time , int period ,boolean repeat ,int    id ){







    AlarmManager al = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


   Intent i = new Intent(c,AlarmReciever.class);


    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c,7896,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if(repeat ){

        al.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,period,pi);

    }else {
        al.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stop the broadcast receiver when you quit the app:

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    something.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

That way the broadcast listener wont send any notifications, while the app is off. When the user starts the app, you turn on the broadcast receiver again.

**Edit:** 
This is onCreate():

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
filter.addDataScheme("package");
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
registerReceiver(newPackageReceiver, filter); // This is how you register the receiver.
```

And this is the functionality of the receiver: This is outside onCreate():

```
private final BroadcastReceiver newPackageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New App Installed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

So when I want to register the receiver I do like this:

```
registerReceiver(newPackageReceiver, filter);
```

And when I want to turn it off:

```
unregisterReceiver(newPackageReceiver);
```

So you should start your receiver in the onStop() method, and stop it in onCreate(), and maybe onResume(); . Please thumbs up if this helps.

Comment: Thanks,but I need the opposite , I need the broadcast receiver to send notification when the app is off not on.

Comment: Well then, register the receiver in the onStop() method, and stop it onCreate(); So when the app starts, it will turn off the broadcast receiver, and when you stop the app, it will turn it on again.

Comment: Thanks, But please help me , how I could turn on and turn off the broadcast receiver, and please could you tell me what does you mean in something.unregisterListener(this);, what is (something ).

Comment: I have tried the code above , but I had exception :illegalArgumentException:Rciever not registered(name of reciever), I tried to fix it for many hours , I tried to  put the unregisterReceiver(newPackageReceiver); into try,catch but the exception still happened, please if you know why this happend with me , help me .

Comment: This is the set of alarm in oncreate:

Comment: I have used the solutions above to reach to my solution , I have used sharedpreference and I set the value of it in onDestroy() to integer value e.g 3 and onResume() to a,other integer value e.g 4 in homepage, when the broadcast receiver called , I check the value of sharedpreference and then determine if app is turn on (if value=4) or turn off(value=3), if it is turn on the notification don't notify, but if the app is off the notification is notify, this solution work good with me.